# How to listen to Postgres listen/notify in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, queue, supervisord, worker

## My task in general

I need to listen to a Postgres tables changes (CRUD) done e.g. via a database manager like DBeaver  and pass updated rows id's to a laravel-driven API enpoint.

## What I have

### Postgres part

In Postgres I create a table, a trigger for my table and a functions which handles the event at postgres side

```sql
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.TBLEXAMPLE
(
  KEY1 CHARACTER VARYING(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY2 CHARACTER VARYING(14) NOT NULL,
   VALUE1 CHARACTER VARYING(20),
  VALUE2 CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT TBLEXAMPLE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (KEY1, KEY2)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PUBLIC.NOTIFY() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_notify('myevent', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
  RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE COST 100;


CREATE TRIGGER TBLEXAMPLE_AFTER
AFTER insert or update or delete 
ON PUBLIC.TBLEXAMPLE
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE PUBLIC.NOTIFY();
```

### PHP part

I have a basic PHP script which is intended to be run from CLI. When I run it, I get notifications on updates in the PG table

```php
<?php
$db = new PDO(
    "pgsql:dbname=database host=localhost port=5432", 'postgres', 'password', [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    ]
);

$db->exec('LISTEN myevent');
echo 'Starting';

while(true) {
    while ($result = $db->pgsqlGetNotify(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 30000)) {
        echo print_r($result, true) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks

[image]

## Question

What is the correct way to run the PHP above script as a laravel part?

Please point me what to read, maybe a similar solution.

> I know clever words like "worker", "queue", I use `php artisan queue:work` in my API (A user requests an endpoint which adds jobs to the queue). But in this case the role of the user should be performed by the php script logic above.
>
> My suggestion. I probably must develop something like `php artisan listen2posrgres` with the logic from above and run it similar to `php artisan queue:work` throughout supervisor. Can this work?

Comment: php artisan listen2posrgres - this is possible, you just need to create your own custom command and use your existing code. That should be fine in laravel.

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez Any example of such a console command listening to something? Or something you recommend to read.Thanks.

Comment: You could create a console command to listen to the postgres event and then emit a laravel event which you can listen to internally or broadcast if you want to update your UI.

Comment: @Gruz read and follow this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#writing-commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some of the comments indicated, you could write a custom Artisan command for this. Running the command starts "listening" for trigger events.

In PostgreSQL, you can create a Trigger that acts like a Subscriber in Laravel -- observing changes to tables, it gathers data such as the table name and action and passes this to Laravel via `pg_notify` if Laravel has defined a connection to this database. You can use JSON handling to encode the data to pass on to Laravel, which you then parse as JSON encoded as a string.

Here is a simple example for watching an Orders or Users table for UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE.

**Trigger**

```
create function notify_event() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
        notification json;
    BEGIN

        -- PostgreSQL auto-defined variables:
        -- TG_OP    ~   action such as INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
        -- TG_TABLE_NAME

        -- Contruct the notification as a JSON string.
        notification = json_build_object(
                          'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,
                          'action', TG_OP);


        -- Execute pg_notify(channel, notification)
        PERFORM pg_notify('events', notification::text);

        -- Result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
        RETURN NULL;
    END;

$$;

alter function notify_event() owner to YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_HERE;
```

**Artisan Command**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Events\OrderCreated;
use App\Events\OrderDeleted;
use App\Events\OrderUpdated;
use App\Events\UserCreated;
use App\Events\UserDeleted;
use App\Events\UserUpdated;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

/**
 * Class SubscribeToTriggers
 *
 * @package App\Console\Commands
 */
class SubscribeToTriggers extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'psql:subscribe-to-triggers {--t|table=* : Tables to synchronize.}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Listen for changes on database and update the platform accordingly';

    /**
     *  Tables to synchronize.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $tables;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $subscribers;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->tables = [];
        $this->subscribe();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $timeout = (int) $this->option('timeout');

        if ($table = $this->option('table')) {
            if (is_array($table)) {
                $this->tables = $table;
            } else {
                $this->tables[] = $table;
            }
        }

        try {
            $dbo = DB::connection('DATABASE_NAME_HERE')->getPdo();
            $dbo->exec('LISTEN "events"');
            while (true) {
                $event = $dbo->pgsqlGetNotify(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, $timeout * 1000);

                if ($this->output->isDebug()) {
                    $this->getOutput()->write($event);
                    $this->getOutput()->write(PHP_EOL);
                }

                $payload = json_decode($event['payload']);
                $table = $payload->table;
                $action = $payload->action;
                $original = $payload->original;
                $data = $payload->data;

                $observer = null;
                $subject = implode('@', [$table, strtolower($action)]);
                if (array_key_exists($subject, $this->subscribers)) {
                    $observer = $this->subscribers[$subject];
                } else if (array_key_exists($table, $this->subscribers)) {
                    $observer = $this->subscribers[$table];
                }
                if (isset($observer) && method_exists($this, $observer->handler)) {
                    $handler = $observer->handler;
                    $this->$handler($data, $action, $original);
                }
     
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            logger($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set up observers to handle events on a table.
     *
     * @param $entity
     * @param $handler
     */
    private function listen($entity, $handler)
    {
        if (!isset($this->subscribers)) {
            $this->subscribers = [];
        }

        $info = explode('@', $entity);
        $table = $info[0];
        $action = count($info) > 1 ? $info[1] : null;

        $observer = new \stdClass();
        $observer->table = $table;
        $observer->action = $action;
        $observer->handler = $handler;
        $subject = !empty($action) ? implode('@', [$table, strtolower($action)]) : $table;
        $this->subscribers[$subject] = $observer;
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to modification events on these tables.
     */
    private function subscribe()
    {
        $this->listen('orders_table', 'onOrder');
        $this->listen('users_table', 'onUser');
    }

    /**
     * @param $order
     * @param null $action
     * @param null $original
     */
    protected function onOrder($order, $action = null, $original = null)
    {
        $event = null;

        if ($action == 'INSERT') {
            $event = new OrderCreated();
        } else if ($action === 'UPDATE') {
            $event = new OrderUpdated();
        } else if ($action == 'DELETE') {
            $event = new OrderDeleted();
        }

        if (!is_null($event)) {
            event($event);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $user
     * @param null $action
     * @param null $original
     */
    protected function onUser($user, $action = null, $original = null)
    {
        $event = null;

        if ($action == 'INSERT') {
            $event = new UserCreated();
        } else if ($action === 'UPDATE') {
            $event = new UserUpdated();
        } else if ($action == 'DELETE') {
            $event = new UserDeleted();
        }

        if (!is_null($event)) {
            event($event);
        }
    }

}
```

Then you would write a Laravel Subscriber to define EventListeners for each of the events defined in the command:

- OrderCreated / OrderUpdated / OrderDeleted
- UserCreated / UserUpdated / UserDeleted

And make sure to register this Subscriber in the $subscribers block of EventServiceProvider.

**References**

[PostgreSQL Triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-trigger.html)
[PostgreSQL JSON and Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)
[Laravel Events: Subscribers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/events#event-subscribers)

Comment: This is exactly what I want too but I am struggling to implement it. Right now stuck with error: `Trying to access array offset on value of type bool` on line `$payload  = json_decode($event['payload']);`